# Inner flow was completed without producing result elements for 1 outstanding elements

Tags: scala, playframework

I had a working play framework application. I tried to enable Database evolution support on the application. I changed the application.conf file by adding following settings

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/scaladb"
db.default.username=scalauser
db.default.password=******
db.default.poolInitialSize=1
db.default.poolMaxSize=5
db.default.ConnectionTimeoutMillis=1000
play.evolutions.autoApply=true
```

The database exists and I can connect to it using command like `sql -U scalauser -d scaladb`

I added the following lines to my AppLoader class to setup the database and run migrations

```
val onStart = {
  applicationEvolutions
  DBs.setupAll()
}

applicationLifecycle.addStopHook{() => 
  DBs.closeAll()
  Future.successful(Unit)
}
```

but now when I run my application by `set run` I get this mysterious error message which actually means nothing. I'm not even sure that is the framework trying to tell me

```
akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException: Inner flow was completed without producing result elements for 1 outstanding elements
at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$One2OneBidi$$anon$1$$anon$4.onUpstreamFinish(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:97)
at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:504)
at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:472)
at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:563)
at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OK. I figured it out. the problem is that the config file is malformed. The lines

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.username=scalauser
db.default.password=******
```

Should be written as

```
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.username="scalauser"
db.default.password="password"
```

But it's funny that rather than say that the application conf file has missing `"`  play framework throws a very cryptic error message.

Comment: In my case it was in the configuration too but not because of the missing `"`but because I wrote a Windows Path without escaping. I got this error if for exemple I have `myconfig="c:\folder\"` but all goes back to normal if we escape the Windows Parth like this `myconfig="c:\\folder\\"` (double back slashe).

Comment: Any malformed `application.conf` seems to trigger this. For example, `uploadURL=http://localhost:8080/api/upload` (without quotes). A colon : is not allowed in an unquoted string (https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#unquoted-strings). If you hate this too, comment on https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/10744

Comment: Thanks for hint, in my case it was a ENV var not being set myval:${NON_EXISTANT_ENV_VAR}

Answer (score 0):

By answering this question, I want to highlight the comment on the accepted answer.

Carefully check the environment variables defined in the *application.conf* file. In my case, I had one undefined environment variable. My solution was to add the definition in the kubernetes pod configuration yaml.