# Play Framework 2.7 cryptic akka exception

Tags: java, scala, playframework, akka, akka-http

We're on version 2.7 of Play Framework and we've been getting what seems like a random exception in the logs (see below), however we can not seem to trace it back to our code. Here is the stack trace:

```
[2020-07-15 14:02:36,294] - [ERROR] - from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl at [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(application)] 
Internal server error, sending 500 response
akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException: Inner flow was completed without producing result elements for 1 outstanding elements
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$One2OneBidi$$anon$1$$anon$4.onUpstreamFinish(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:97)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:506)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:376)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:606)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:485)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:581)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:749)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:764)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:671)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:614)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:583)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

As you can see there are no references to any non-play code. The play app runs normally with visible problems in functionality. Googling hasn't yielded much insight apart from similar issues due to malformed config files (which causes the same stack trace but under different conditions) and possibly Kamon related issues. We do use kamon version 1 . What could be causing this exception? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58583155/7550592

Comment: yeah i saw that SO question. It's not that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is caused by this issue:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/9020

Meaning that your configuration is malformed (it couldn't be parsed). Hitting `ctrl+c` should at least show another error message with more information about where the error is.

Comment: Nope this isn't the issue. The config file is not malformed and my app runs normally (aside from the random exceptions in the log)